# Populating DB field Django

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, django

Django Model - **Person** where id is primary key                              **exercises** where id is a foreign key to person and an int field for exercise score.

HTML to do a simple radio button quiz - and then JavaScript to compute the score of said quiz. I then need to take the exercise score and return it to the database ( i.e. in 'exercise score' of model exercises. )

I'm just looking for some references I can use for returning a value from HTML/JavaScript to a django model database field(MySQL). Really just need pointing into the right direction on the type of topics I should be looking into/resource :]

Answer (score 1):

These are very fundamental questions, so I would say maybe start with the [Django Getting Started](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/) tutorial?

It will take you through creating a model, accessing that model data in a view, and then passing that data into your template - which I believe addresses your question.

Your question is very broad, so this answer is broad. The tutorial won't discuss writing javascript, that's a different topic not related to Django, but that js will go in your django templates.

You might have some MySQL related questions too, but I'd suggest starting with SQLite so you don't have to deal with any database setup to start with.